Branch code coverage is not 100% for code with async/await
When writing tests in my project, I came across the fact that the code coverage in the branch column is not 100%. Using NODE_V8_COVERAGE=v8_coverage I found a place that is not covered by the test, but I don’t understand why it occurs and how to bypass it. Personally, I'm more interested in the reason why this happens.
Example code:
b.mjs:
import test, { describe, it } from 'node:test';
import assert from 'assert';

function f() {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('err 1'));
}

describe('tests', async () => {
    it('test 1', async () => {
        await assert.rejects(
            async () => {
                await f();
            },
            (err) => {
                assert.ok(err instanceof Error);
                return true;
            },
        );
    });
});

NODE_V8_COVERAGE=v8_coverage node --experimental-test-coverage b.mjs:
ℹ ------------------------------------------------------
ℹ file  | line % | branch % | funcs % | uncovered lines
ℹ ------------------------------------------------------
ℹ b.mjs | 100.00 |    85.71 |  100.00 | 
ℹ ------------------------------------------------------
ℹ all … | 100.00 |    85.71 |  100.00 |
ℹ ------------------------------------------------------

In the v8_coverage folder I found the following:
    {
      "functionName": "",
      "ranges": [
        { "startOffset": 248, "endOffset": 302, "count": 1 },
        { "startOffset": 288, "endOffset": 301, "count": 0 }
      ],
      "isBlockCoverage": true
    },

{ "startOffset": 248, "endOffset": 302, "count": 1 }, is 'async () => {\n                await f();\n            },'
{ "startOffset": 288, "endOffset": 301, "count": 0 } is '\n            }'
For a normal exception, coverage is 100%.
a.mjs:
import test, { describe, it } from 'node:test';
import assert from 'assert';

function g() {
    throw new Error('err 2');
}

describe('tests', async () => {
    it('test 1', async () => {
        assert.throws(
            () => {
                g();
            },
            (err) => {
                assert.ok(err instanceof Error);
                return true;
            },
        );
    });
});

NODE_V8_COVERAGE=v8_coverage node --experimental-test-coverage a.mjs:
...

ℹ ------------------------------------------------------
ℹ file  | line % | branch % | funcs % | uncovered lines
ℹ ------------------------------------------------------
ℹ a.mjs | 100.00 |   100.00 |  100.00 | 
ℹ ------------------------------------------------------
ℹ all … | 100.00 |   100.00 |  100.00 |
ℹ ------------------------------------------------------

There is no additional item in the v8_coverage folder:
  "functions": [
    {
      "functionName": "",
      "ranges": [{ "startOffset": 0, "endOffset": 406, "count": 1 }],
      "isBlockCoverage": true
    },
    {
      "functionName": "g",
      "ranges": [{ "startOffset": 78, "endOffset": 124, "count": 1 }],
      "isBlockCoverage": true
    },
    {
      "functionName": "",
      "ranges": [{ "startOffset": 144, "endOffset": 404, "count": 1 }],
      "isBlockCoverage": true
    },
    {
      "functionName": "",
      "ranges": [{ "startOffset": 175, "endOffset": 400, "count": 1 }],
      "isBlockCoverage": true
    },
    {
      "functionName": "",
      "ranges": [{ "startOffset": 224, "endOffset": 266, "count": 1 }],
      "isBlockCoverage": true
    },
    {
      "functionName": "",
      "ranges": [{ "startOffset": 280, "endOffset": 382, "count": 1 }],
      "isBlockCoverage": true
    }
  ]

Update
Found a way around this using .catch:
import test, { describe, it } from 'node:test';
import assert from 'assert';

function f() {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('err 1'));
}

async function rejects(cb, cbErr) {
    let wasError = false;
    await (cb().catch(err => {
        wasError = true;
        cbErr(err);
    }));
    assert.ok(wasError);
}

describe('tests', async () => {
    it('test 1', async () => {
        await rejects(f, (err) => {
            assert.ok(err instanceof Error);
        });
    });
});

Update 2
Another way without using async lambda:
import test, { describe, it } from 'node:test';
import assert from 'assert';

function f() {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('err 1'));
}

describe('tests', async () => {
    it('test 1', async () => {
        await assert.rejects(
            f,
            (err) => {
                assert.ok(err instanceof Error);
                return true;
            },
        );
    });
});

